# How to use apply function on multiple columns at once

Tags: python, pandas, apply, duration, timedelta

Is it possible to call the apply function on multiple columns in pandas and if so how does one do this.. for example,

```
 df['Duration'] = df['Hours', 'Mins', 'Secs'].apply(lambda x,y,z: timedelta(hours=x, minutes=y, seconds=z))
```

[This is what the expected output should look like once everything comes together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdKpV.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You should use:**

```
df['Duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.Hours*3600 + df.Mins*60 + df.Secs, unit='s')
```

When you use apply on a `DataFrame` with `axis=1`, it's a row calculation, so typically this syntax makes sense:

```
df['Duration'] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Timedelta(hours=row.Hours, minutes=row.Mins, 
    seconds=row.Secs), axis=1)
```

Some timings

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Hours': np.tile([1,2,3,4],50),
                  'Mins':  np.tile([10,20,30,40],50),
                  'Secs': np.tile([11,21,31,41],50)})

%timeit pd.to_timedelta(df.Hours*3600 + df.Mins*60 + df.Secs, unit='s')
#432 µs ± 5.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df.apply(lambda row: pd.Timedelta(hours=row.Hours, minutes=row.Mins, seconds=row.Secs), axis=1)
#12 ms ± 67.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

As always, apply should be a last resort.

Comment: Hi i tried your solution but i keep getting this error: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Comment: @Blank You need to make sure you're actually using `apply` on a `DataFrame` and not a `Series`. `Series.apply()` has no axis argument, which is the likely cause of that error [Series apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply)

Comment: But again, DO NOT use the apply method here. It's extremely slow for larger DataFrames.

Comment: okay so is the first line of code the main suggestion you're making? ALSO, why are you multiplying by 3600? cus when i use the first line i get the following error: int too big to convert

Comment: It seemed to me that you had a `DataFrame` with 3 columns `Hours`, `Mins` and `Secs` which were all integers. I was calculating the total time in seconds, then using pd.to_timedelta with the unit of seconds. But it seems that's not what you have. You should post your data with print(df) so that we can actually help you with what you really have.

Comment: Hi i would love to post my data but I've been instructed not to edit my question after 3 answers have been posted and i'm not sure exactly the way to attach a screenshot

Comment: Thank you! I finally figured out what was going on!

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply` on the dataframe with `axis=1` 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

`triangles = [{ 'base': 20, 'height': 9 }, { 'base': 10, 'height': 7 }, { 'base': 40, 'height': 4 }]`

`triangles_df = pd.DataFrame(triangles)`

`def calculate_area(row):
    return row['base'] * row['height'] * 0.5`

`triangles_df.apply(calculate_area, axis=1)`

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as DT
df = pd.DataFrame({"Hours": [1], "Mins": [2], "Secs": [10]})
df = df.astype(int)

df['Duration'] = df[['Hours', 'Mins', 'Secs']].apply(lambda x: DT.timedelta(hours=x[0], minutes=x[1], seconds=x[2]), axis=1)

print(df)
print(df["Duration"])
```

**Output:**

```
   Hours  Mins  Secs  Duration
0      1     2    10  01:02:10

0   01:02:10
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: This certainly is helpful but I'm getting this error: ('index out of bounds', 'occurred at index 0')